# UIImages not recovered Once Device is Restarted

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ios8, nsdocumentdirectory

In iOS 8, I am writing UIImages on the device using the code

```
 NSString *documentsDirectory = nil;
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *pathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%ld",documentsDirectory, @"ProfileImage", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PatientsId"]];
 NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 40);////I have replaced it with UIImagePNGRepresentation as well
 [imageData writeToFile: pathString atomically:YES];
```

The write to file is successful.
If I try to recover the image using the function,

```
    NSArray *documentDirectories =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// Get one and only document directory from that list
NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *pathString =[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%ld", @"ProfileImage", (long)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"PatientsId"]]] ;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: pathString];
```

The image is recovered.
However, if I restart the device, the images are not there anymore. The function [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: pathString] returns nil and if I use  NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: pathString];, the myData is nil as well.

This procedure was working perfectly fine prior to iOS 8, however, it isn't working properly anymore. Can someone please guide me what is wrong with this?

Comment: FYI - Not that this is related to the problem but the 2nd parameter value to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` needs to be a number in the range `0.0` to `1.0`.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: Update your question with the code for getting `pathString` when you try to read the images.

Comment: @rmaddy I have changed it, have a look.

Comment: Two things to check: 1) You build the two paths differently. Change so both use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`. 2) In both places, load the `NSUserDefaults` value into a separate variable so you can debug your code and verify that you get the same value both times.

Comment: @rmaddy Actually I have tried it in another way as well. Once the Path string is generated, I am saving it in documents directory as well. Next time, I fetch that path and then tries to recover the image. I have compared path several times, Its exactly the same which was used at the time of writing.

Comment: Do this happen in the simulator or just on the device?

Comment: @mgChristopher It happens on both device and the simulator.

Comment: Everything you are doing looks correct, so lets dig for some more information.  I would like a clarification of what you mean when you say you "restart the device".  Namely what steps are you doing and how are you testing this on the simulator.   Also do you have code that delete those images in your application?   Finally I would run this in the simulator and watch the file location as it is creating the file and see if when it is being deleted and start adding breakpoints.